# Create multiple dynamically named pandas columns and apply a function on it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with OHLC values for an asset from which I can calculate  technical indicators, for example, `EMA` or `SMA` for one `ndays = 10` as follows:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# Get symbol OHLC data
tsla = yf.Ticker("TSLA")
df = tsla.history(period='ytd', interval='1h')
df = df.drop(['Dividends','Stock Splits'], axis=1)

def sma(df, ndays): 
    df['TP'] = (df['High'] + df['Low'] + df['Close']) / 3 
    df['SMA_{}'.format(ndays)] = df['TP'].rolling(ndays).mean()
    return df

df = sma(df,10)
df
```

[image: df result for code above]

**My Problem:**
This would generate one column named `SMA_10`. However, I have a range of values for `ndays` from 2-15 for which I would like to generate a specific named column for each, for example `SMA_2`, `SMA_3`, `SMA_4`,`SMA_5`....`SMA_15`. In the actual data I have to generate over 200 such columns.

**My attempt:**

```
for i in range(2,16):
    if not "SMA_{i}" in df.columns:
        df = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(sma(df,i)), axis=1)
        break
```

However, this does not work as it returns the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is there a way for me to dynamically create such named columns and apply a function on it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At which part of your code do you get the error?

Comment: For the iteration part `for i in range(2,16):` when I try to create multiple columns with the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 mistakes:
First in your function `sma()` you have used `i`instead of `ndays`.
Second, you have build your `sma()` function that it takes a dataframe, however, you have called it with a row. (The variable `row` was not used either) By directly calling `sma()` you will get the result:

```
for i in range(2,16):
    if not "SMA_{i}" in df.columns:
        df = sma(df,i)
        # break # Add for debugging purpose
```

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected it to `ndays`, however, the `df` still returns one column `SMA_2`  in this case. I would like to generate multiple numbered columns for SMA values.

Comment: *You* have added a `break` command to the function. Thus, after the first excecution it will end. Just remove the `break`